# Use jQuery in Node without installing Python/VCBuild.exe

Tags: jquery, node.js, jsdom

I'm trying to write a Node application which uses jQuery.

To use jQuery in Node, you need to provide it with a window object. There seem to be a number of ways to do this, but the most common seems to be to use JSDom to create the window object.

The problem is, to use JSDom, you need to install both Python and have VCBuild.exe available (and get the PATH set up properly).

This greatly increases the difficulty of sharing what I'm writing with the rest of my team. They'd each have to set up these additional dependencies on their computer, meaning it's a lot more complicated than just "clone repo and run npm install".

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You do realize that Node is server side code while JQuery is clientside code? Or are you referring to a different type of JQuery?

Comment: I'm basically writing something which needs to be able to parse and manipulate the HTML DOM. Compared to the other options, jQuery seems the easiest. If I was going to not use jQuery, JSDom is the next likely candidate on its own, but it's the source of my trouble to begin with.

Comment: Since xHTML is XML-based, you can use an XML parser effectively. There are also HTML parser modules such as HTMLParser, HTMLParser2 that you can use. Using JQuery on the server is just....... **yuck**

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD That only counts if I'm using XHTML, and if the XHTML is valid. Invalid XHTML won't work with an XML parser. I'll have to use a DOM parser, which still requires python.

Comment: I'm positive that Node has a DOM Parser that doesn't require jQuery; all server-based languages have it. Using jQuery is still.... **yucky**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio)

> Tiny, fast, and elegant implementation of core jQuery designed specifically for the server

Answer (score 0):

don't use jquery in node. really.
i needed the jquery extends capability and someone wrote a node module for that (node.extends).
every functionality you need, you will have a node module for. trust me.
don't go with putting pure client library in server.

there are libraries which are good for both client/server like underscore but they are rare and even underscore is packaged as a node module for nodejs.

Comment: I need to do something that does a lot of HTML DOM parsing and manipulating. jQuery has those capabilities which is what I'm after. If I use something that just replicates the DOM, then it's the same as just using the DOM directly on the client-side. It's certainly doable, but less convenient. If I leave jQuery, I still would need something like JSDom, so it's still a problem.

Comment: If you want to manipulate the dom, why to not simply refer to your jquery lib in your main parent template ? It s pretty common with other server sides languages/framework like Symfony 2 in php

Comment: @Skahrz I'm not building a website. I'm building a templating system for use with creating "code comps". This is a tool to allow us to use a few basic HTML elements to provide templating (can't of like Handlebars). There isn't a "client side" for this.